# How do can I know if my xbox damages discs

Tags: xbox-360

About a week ago while i was playing my friend took console up and it started making awful voices, game cd was damaged and i want to know if it's bad for xbox? Console is making voices when disc  is in

Answer (score 1):

Damaged CDs are not, persay, bad for the console.  The console, however, is rather bad for discs.  Since a damaged disc won't be readable in some sections, it's usually a good idea not to use the console until you resolve the issue.  Unless you happen to like resurfacing or replacing your disks on a regular basis.

If your console is making bad sounds when there's a disk in it, and it comes out damaged, it's pretty safe to say your console is damaging the disks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to test it by running an old cd or dvd you don't care about. Any Xbox will chew up a disc if moved whilst on and this (usually) does not cause major damage